# struts2 session maintenance with glassfish server

Tags: java

In my application there is a 5 min session timeout.

```
<session-config>
    <session-properties>
        <property name="timeoutSeconds" value="300"></property>
    </session-properties>
</session-config>
```

On the client there are several timers which are polling (calling struts2 actions) in every 30 sec so my session is never go to timeout.

How can I achieve that the session timer ignore some calls, which I want to ignore? I'm thinking about a parameter that I pass to every timer's calls and maybe check this in some interceptor. What is the right solution for this?

I didn't find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this out, from timer calls I send a parameter and I check in interceptor.